# Logistic Lasso on large gene dataset specifically through the Knockoff package in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, large-data, lasso-regression

This question is perhaps in an uncanny valley between CrossValidated and StackOverflow, as I'm trying to understand the methodology of functions in an R package, in the context of executing them properly.

The data is gene expression; with thousands of variables. Outcome is a binary variable.

I have managed to get a logistic lasso from `glmnet` but I've been asked to do it again with the `knockoff` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knockoff/index.html

The problem is, if I've understood the vignettes correctly, the choices in the package are (a) assume the response variable is a normal (not true lol) or (b) pre-specify the distribution, mu, and sigma of the predictors. Perhaps it is my inexperience showing, but I don't feel confident this dataset can work for either of those things. Those who have tasked me with this cryptically insist the package works for logistic lasso, though.

Am I missing something? How would one go about doing a logistic lasso on a massive dataset using `knockoff`?

Answer (score 0):

I found this quite tricky to work out, but I think the code below should work with a logistic lasso model. I found the `stat.lasso_coefdiff_bin` function in the `knockoff` package, which I think is internally building a logistic lasso model, then computing knockoff statistics by comparing coefficients of original and knockoff predictors.

```
library(knockoff)
library(glmnet)
library(mlbench)
data("PimaIndiansDiabetes2", package = "mlbench")
df <- na.omit(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)

# Prepare the example data
X <- as.matrix(df[, -ncol(df)])
y <- ifelse(df$diabetes == "pos", 1, 0)
    
# Select variables
selected_vars <- knockoff::knockoff.filter(X, y, create.fixed, fdr=0.5, statistic=knockoff::stat.lasso_coefdiff_bin)
```

With my example data I could only get this to actually select some variables by making the false discovery rate (`fdr`) quite high. I'm not sure what an appropriate value might be. It will probably depend on your data, so I suggest trying it out with something lower first, maybe 0.1. You would also want to check what function to use to generate your knockoffs - I've used `create.fixed` but you can also use `create.gaussian`.

Hope that helps